# Missing views from custom layout in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-menu

I am trying to make a custom Navigation Drawer with images and title underneath, like in the following image;

[image: Menu Items]

So this is my layout I named: **menu_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_icon"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Menu Title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_menu"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and finally the menu; **activity_main_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item"/>
</menu>
```

The result I get is missing the TextView, what could be the issue here?

my result: [image: Result]

Thanks

Comment: Change the `RelativeLayout` in **menu_item.xml** to a `LinearLayout`

Comment: try adding `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_menu"` to the `TextView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use simple `LinearLayout` and apply `android:gravity="center"` to the root layout. also remove parent margin `android:layout_margin="10dp"`

the `textview` is out of the viewport in menu items

try this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Menu Title"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Great answer thank you, it fixed the visibility issue but I still have the problem with centering the whole item inside the navigation drawer, do you have a fix for that please?
EDIT: Also I want to make the item a little bigger on the height, what do I do?